# jQuery to read json data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to get jquery to read json data but getting undefined.

```
            $.post( wce_data.url, { userid : userId, token : accessToken }, 'json')
          .done(function( data ) {
            console.log("data.status: " + data.status);
            if (data.status === "success") {
              alert("Coupon added");
            } else {
              alert("failed");
            }
          })
          .fail(function() {
            alert("The requested action failed. Please contact the site administrator!");
          });
```

data.status: returns 'undefined'
data: returns {"status":"success"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I see. I got it. It was the PHP Output Header that was needed.
I added:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

To the PHP for jQuery.

Hope this helped someone new to json like me.

Answer (score 0):

Try error checking like this:

```
.done(function() {
    alert( "Coupon added" );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
```

Comment: The result goes to .done but I am just not getting the data.status. Thank you for your reply